# Clickatell Connect API - No XML Data found

Tags: java, post, https, xml-parsing, clickatell

I'm trying to use Clickatell's Connect API ( http://www.clickatell.com/downloads/Clickatell_Connect_API_User_Guide.pdf?cid=205655 ) in order to create users and send sms. Clickatell's API provides you with a specific URL that you have to submit a case-sensitive XML as an HTTPS form post.

I've written the following simple xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CLICKATELLSDK>
<Action>get_list_country</Action>
</CLICKATELLSDK>
```

and I have used various code sample online (some taken from answer from stackoverflow, other from google searches - i.e. http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-send-an-xml-document-to-a-remote-web-server-using-http-5.html )on how to submit it as an HTTPS POST, but I always get the following responce.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CLICKATELLSDK>
<Result>Error</Result>
<Error>999</Error>
<Description>No XML Data found</Description>
<Timestamp>1353538744</Timestamp>
</CLICKATELLSDK>
```

Anyone using Clickatell's Connect API that can help me out or does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the following code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpPost {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String postUrl = "https://connect.clickatell.com/[AuthenticationToken]";

            try {
                String tStatus = "";
                URL url = new URL(postUrl + "&XML=<clickatellsdk><action>get_list_country</action></clickatellsdk>");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    tStatus = line;
                    System.out.println(tStatus);
                }

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Handle Exception
            }

    }

}
```

Let me know if you don't come right, so we can tackle it further!

Comment: It worked flawlessly - many thanks for that. I was thinking that there might be some encoding problems with the file, or maybe the server might needed the file to be of some specific encoding in order to "read" the request... Anyhow, I wasn't planning of sending single xml files to the server anyway (the option to create full strings with the request is just perfect) so I have to thank you twice! Keep rocking man (y)